# iOS Support for PWA App Store Upload and Push Notifications

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

Discussion:
In the future, will iOS support uploading PWAs to the App store and providing push notifications for PWAs?
Has anyone successfully pushed a PWA to the app store yet, and which tools have they used for the process?

I tried to push a PWA to the App Store but was not successful.

Comment: I am also trying upload my PWA app to appstore. Can you share more details about what was not successful in your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple supports Web Push for Web Apps on iOS and iPadOS from iOS/iPadOS 16.4: https://webkit.org/blog/13878/web-push-for-web-apps-on-ios-and-ipados/.

I can see

> Added support for Web Push in web apps saved to the home screen on iOS

on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information and the links for Web Push in web apps on iOS and iPadOS from version 16.4.
I will try to add Web Push to my website and test this version.